# IIS 8.5 1 Domain two IP Direction

Tags: ip, iis-8.5

I'm looking to configure a domain to go to two places based on the URL provided.

1: domain.com and www.domain.com (this domain direct to first IP)

2: *.domain.com redirect to second IP (examples: company.domain.com, company2.domain.com)

The first site is the main public website and the second is an SSL-encrpyted back end.'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Domain names are resolved to IP numbers by the DNS System. [See Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) and some  [explanation of record types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types). [Orcweb](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/mark-newnam/how-to-set-up-site-bindings-in-internet-information-services-iis/) has an article about IIS Site bindings to do the rest of the mapping to sites.

Comment: I know that, thank you. I was thinking the * host record would include the www but I read it does not. I'll take a look at the articles.